# Can I update a displacement , or should that go automaticly?

Tags: animation, modifiers

I made a long corridor, it's to have a video, for a music track of mine.

I was using an mp3 before, now added a newer version of the track, a wave file for better sound quality.

Deleted keyframes, made new ones, displacement modifyer, strength, bake sound to f curves.

It worked but, I can't shake the feeling only the first displacements is updated.
( the one I had selected )
Looks like all the others are still reacting to the mp3.

Is there a way to check this, to what music track a displacement is linked.
And or how to edit this. I made allot of copies, of the planes with the modifyer, before I added the wave file.

I hope I won't have to learn phyton for this. :P

Comment: That depends. How are you driving your displacement? Are you using different sound bakes for each, or drivers reading from one central bake?

Comment: Thank you.

One song should drive all, not using multiple sounds.

This might help ? It's what I have now, I am talking about the red lights.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfZiGGszePE

Those all need to be updated to the .wave file.
I fear I only did it for the first one. 

Used this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=11&v=l8RHRNZQEuE&feature=emb_logo

Comment: I just did a test, and worst case, will be me having to allot of copy paste. 

In the graph editor the first few letters of the file (music track) are displayed.
If I give the file a different name, add some letters infront, then I can see if all get updated or just one. 

Unless there is a way to copy, the bake to f curve data, from one displacement to another?

Comment: I can really recommend animation nodes for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjYf-tD2SqM . You have a ton of fine control, you won't need any baking, everything is real-time and you can do so much more than what you have so far (not that it's missing anything, but if you want, you can do much more, easily)

Comment: Thank you, since I will have to do all (red lights) again anyway, will try with nodes.

Something interesting about his approach, he is moving bars instead of a surface.
He also makes them change colour, something I was wondering about but probably wont look good nice for my corriodor.

Comment: My edit time seems to have expired, so two more questions this way.

Can I copy nodes from one mesh to another, or link more meshes to the nodes ?
 
I hope I won't have to do that node thing 40 - 50 times ?

Comment: Meshes? You can duplicate nodes, the AN are not bound to meshes and I would recomment not to use more than one node tree per scene. The beauty about animation nodes is that you can do the same thing to as many objects as you want using a loop.

Comment: The red light jumping in my vid, I call that meshes. Should I call them faces ? 

Rough guess, I have over 40 of them. Current corridor is at least 4 times as long, as the one in the vid. I need to fix all of them.  

So basically I need to delete all 40 displacements ? 
Then add those faces to the node?

Comment: Trying to follow the tutorial you linked, but in my blender I can't find the note editor.
There is on a texture node editor.  blendr version 2.83

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_FdTw0JusU&t=44s for installation. The nodes are not bound to meshes, they are all in one tree. If you set up a behaviour, you can copy that to ALL objects by putting them in a group and use a loop to iterate over all of them

Comment: I just installed the AN.

Will give it a try. 

Fixed my original issue by deleting all displacements, then made a new one and copy  pasted that about 40 times.

If all went well I should have a copy of the file were all displacements are deleted.
In there I will try the AN, then I can see if that way the music track can easily be updated.

Comment: You are using a computer, everytime you're doing the same thing more than 3 times, you can ask yourself: Can't the machine do that for me? With animation nodes the answer more often than not is yes.

Comment: Looking back, I think there is a better Blender way to do allot of what I have done, array along a path to name one, for creating a long corridor with a few bends. 

It's something I need to investigate. 

I did try it that way, but run into allot of issues. One was about stubborn children (parenting)  This is my first blender project though, so trouble was expected.
Solved that by allot of copy paste and modelling, 45 degree corner pieces. 
Select vertices, Spin ( number of steps 1) , F to fill , extrude the newly created plane.

Comment: With AN you could solve that with a few nodes (also distribution along a path, there's a node for that) and it's flexible, too, so minor changes are instant.

Comment: I am worried about array along a path. I might have to do allot of tweaking on the path.

Although it might be easier if I just do the hull separate, then add pipes and all in a second array. 

But if it works, making the corridor go up and down, and maybe even more, would be allot easier.

I did not have much issues when I just did the hull along a path array.
Trouble started with parented stuff. Maybe I can't use a wire frame along a path array.
( floor meshes)